# What are the effects of the different pylons?

Tags: diablo-iii

Pylons appear in Nephalem Rifts and appear to basically be a souped up version of the shrines, but last for less time. So far I have seen stones that:

- Provide damage immunity
- Boost damage output 400%
- Make me a giant power plant that electrocutes and kills everything in
  my path

Are there any others?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are [5 pylon types](http://www.diablofans.com/news/47876-reaper-of-souls-highlights-nephalem-rift-pylons):

1. Shield - Impervious to damage for 30 seconds.
2. Conduit - Lightning zaps your surroundings for 30 seconds.  (Does a LOT of damage)
3. Power - All attacks do +400% damage for 30 seconds.
4. Speed - Maximum run speed for 30 seconds.
5. Channeling - All resource costs and are removed for 30 seconds and cooldown is vastly decreased.

Comment: Conduit is absolutely devastating.  If you're playing on higher difficulties, you can use conduit and take out elite packs/bosses in seconds.  My first time I found one, I had *just* cleared out the last of the champions and the boss, was so disappointed.

Comment: I think Speed Pylon gives a fixed bonus, over max, to move speed "maximum run speed for 30 seconds" seems misleading. You move even faster still when using certain skills while under speed pylon. Just a thought.

Comment: Conduit truly is devestating. It was so exciting this first time I activated one and just sprinted through and entire level!

Comment: Conduit + Nemesis bracers are really good :P

Comment: Speed Pylon puts my monk at 100%, with 25% base.  Not sure if it adds onto other things.

Answer (score 5):

The following Pylons can be found inside Nephalem Rifts. The effects last for 30 seconds.

- **Power** - +400% damage
- **Shield** - Damage immunity
- **Speed** - Greatly increased run speed
- **Conduit** - Lightning strikes nearby monsters and
  surroundings for very high damage
- **Channeling** - All resource costs
  removed, cooldowns greatly reduced.

Comment: z- just edged you out on post time, but thanks for your answer!